# JQuery Checkboxes Group check

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

All,

I have the following code. How can I fix it so that the category checkbox for each category is checked only if all the items under that are checked?

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script>
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
 function toggleTableRows()
 {
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img.parent')
           .css("cursor","pointer")
           .toggle(
              function() {
                 $(this).attr("title","Click to Collapse")
                 $(this).attr("src","arrow_expanded.gif");
                 $('tr').siblings('#child-'+this.id).toggle();
              },
              function() {
                 $(this).attr("title","Click to Expand");
                 $(this).attr("src","arrow_collapsed.gif");
                 $('tr').siblings('#child-'+this.id).toggle();
              }
          );

          initCheckBoxes();
  });
}

function toggleCheckboxes(current, form, field) {
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#"+ form +" :checkbox[name^='"+ field +"[']").attr("checked", current.checked);
     });
}

function toggleParentCheckboxes(current, form) {        
        var checked = ($("#"+ form +" :checkbox[name='"+ current.name +"']").length == $("#"+ form +" :checkbox[name='"+ current.name +"']:checked").length);
        // replace '[anything]' with '' instead of just '[]'
        $("#"+ form +" :checkbox[name='"+ current.name.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/, "") +"']").attr("checked", checked);

}

function initCheckBoxes(form) {
    $("#"+ form +" :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
                  if (this.name.match(/chk[0-9]\[.*\]/)) {
            toggleParentCheckboxes(this, form);
        }
    });
}
</script>
<script language="JavaScript">toggleTableRows();</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="frmDinnerMenu" id="frmDinnerMenu" method="POST" action="">
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td><img class="parent" id="0" src="arrow_collapsed.gif" title="Click to Expand">Category - Fruits</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk0" onclick="toggleCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu', 'chk0');"/></td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;" id="child-0">
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Apple</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" name="chk0[1]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;" id="child-0">
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Banana</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked value="0" name="chk0[2]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td>
</tr>
<tr style="display: none;" id="child-0">
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Orange</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked value="0" name="chk0[5]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td>
</tr>

<tr><td><img class="parent" id="1" src="arrow_collapsed.gif" title="Click to Expand">Category - Vegetables</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="chk1" onclick="toggleCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu', 'chk1');"/></td></tr>
<tr style="display: none;" id=child-1><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cabbage</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked value="0" name="chk1[21]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td></tr>
<tr style="display: none;" id=child-1><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Tomatoes</td><td><input type="checkbox" value="0" name="chk1[26]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td></tr>
<tr style="display: none;" id=child-1><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Green Peppers</td><td><input type="checkbox" checked value="0" name="chk1[29]" onclick="toggleParentCheckboxes(this, 'frmDinnerMenu');"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would be much simpler to answer and for you work, if you html wasn't such a mess

Comment: I don't see how it's a mess.. All simple examples do not explain every complication. It's easy for you to paste it in an html file and view it in a browser and take it from there.

Comment: Anything that contains "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cabbage" is by definition, "a mess".

Comment: That was just for example sakes.. get over it and stop whining !!

Comment: If you had a clue of how to answer the question, that shouldn't matter.. !!!!

Comment: Getting all defensive and whatnot probably isn't the best approach since you're the one who needs help.

Comment: Agreeing with the others - when asking someone for their help, it's best to provide a legible question and not insult their intelligence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gave it a try + some notes which you really should apply too

Some things I fixed to be able to work with this thing

- missing title attribute in head (added)
- Both img-tags have invalid numeric-only id (changed to make a valid id)
- Multiple tr's with id child-0 (made ids unique but still based on img id)
- Multiple tr's with id child-1 (made ids unique but still based on img id)
- alt attribute on both img-tags missing (added)
- too-many inline javascript onclick handlers  (removed/ replaced with jQuery bindings and jQuery to find right parameters)
- too-many inline css on some tr's  (removed/replaced with css class)
- missing type attribute on the script tags  (added)
- initcheckboxes is called without parameter, thus won't work as selector (added param to toggleTableRows)
- made some of the jQuery foo more flexible and robust

Fixed HTML + javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ascii">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
    google.load("jqueryui", "1.7.2");
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function toggleTableRows(form) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('img.parent')
          .css("cursor","pointer")
          .toggle(function() {
            var x = $(this);
            x.attr("title","Click to Collapse")
              .attr("src","arrow_expanded.gif");
            x.parents("tr").eq(0).siblings("[id^=child-"+x.attr("id")+"]").toggle();
          }, function() {
            var x = $(this);
            x.attr("title","Click to Expand")
              .attr("src","arrow_collapsed.gif");
            x.parents("tr").eq(0).siblings("[id^=child-"+x.attr("id")+"]").toggle();
          });
        initCheckBoxes(form);
      });
    }
    function toggleCheckboxes(current, form, field) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#"+ form +" input:checkbox[name^='"+ field +"[']").attr("checked", current.checked);
      });
    }
    function toggleParentCheckboxes(current, form) {
      var name = current.name.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/, "");
      var selected = $("input:checkbox[name^='" + name + "[']");
      var checked = (selected.size() == selected.filter(":checked").size());
      $("#"+ form +" :checkbox[name='" + name + "']").attr("checked", checked);
    }
    function initCheckBoxes(form) {
      $("#"+ form +" input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        if (this.name.match(/chk[0-9]\[.*\]/)) {
          toggleParentCheckboxes(this, form);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">toggleTableRows("frmDinnerMenu");</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("tr:not([id]) input").click(function() {
        var ele = $(this);
        toggleCheckboxes(this, ele.parents("form").eq(0).attr("name"), ele.attr("name"));
        ele=null;
      });
      $("tr[id] input").click(function() {
        toggleParentCheckboxes(this, $(this).parents("form").eq(0).attr("name"))
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">tr.c1 {display: none;}</style>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="frmDinnerMenu" id="frmDinnerMenu" method="post" action="">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td><img class="parent" id="i0" src="arrow_collapsed.gif" alt="fruits" title="Click to Expand" name="0">Category - Fruits</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk0"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c1" id="child-i00">
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" name="chk0[1]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c1" id="child-i01">
        <td>Banana</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked value="0" name="chk0[2]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c1" id="child-i02">
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked value="0" name="chk0[5]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img class="parent" id="i1" src="arrow_collapsed.gif" alt="vegetable" title="Click to Expand" name="1">Category - Vegetables</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk1"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c1" id="child-i10">
        <td>Cabbage</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked value="0" name="chk1[21]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c1" id="child-i11">
        <td>Tomatoes</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="0" name="chk1[26]"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="c1" id="child-i12">
        <td>Green Peppers</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked value="0" name="chk1[29]"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike and Jitter ! I appreciate looking at my code and coming up with a fix. The reason the code is a hodgepodge is:
1. It's one part in a complex thing that I am trying to achieve.
2. I am not lazy about it, but I just wanted to convey to people what I wanted to achieve functionality wise. I understand it's not the cleanest code.
3. Dependencies -- I believe in extending the code functionality to do some more cool things.

It's very hard to explain all this stuff which I want to achieve in a single comment box.. Anyways, Thanks for the suggestions and the replies.. :)

Answer (score 1):

So I'm going to try and answer this question (hey, it's a challenge!).

First let me point out why people don't like your question though:

1. Duplicate ids: id=child-1 appears multiple times, as do others. Ids should be unique, otherwise you'll run into selector problems (getElementById really doesn't like it)
2. Inline javascript: It's hard to determine from looking at the code what actions happen when. You should isolate all functionality in a separate script file. This will make maintenance significantly easier in the future, and allow the browser to cache functionality.
3. &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp  .... consider using "padding-left: 15px". Do it for us.

That all being said, consider using a more targeted selector. In this example, notice **name^=**

```
function toggleParentCheckboxes(current, form) {        
 var name = current.name.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/, "");
 var selector = ":checkbox[name^='" + name + "[']";
 var checked = ($(selector).length == $(selector + ":checked").length);

    $("#"+ form +" :checkbox[name='" + name + "']").attr("checked", checked);
}
```